# get reception time of a packet ns3

Tags: packet, ns-3

Good evening,
I need to know the reception time of a packet. I only found ways to print out the time using callback methods and I cannot use it as a value in my script. Is there any solution to get this information?

Comment: If instead of printing it, you save it to a variable, would it solve your problem? Can you explain your problem further?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to use a function with a return value  as a callback function. But, I found that only a void can be used as a callback method

Answer (score 0):

If by "reception time" you mean the time in your simulation that a packet is received, then you can use `Simulation::Now().GetSeconds()` function to get the current simulation time that your packet is received.

In order to do so, try to connect a callback function to Rx trace for your sink node and print the simulation time there.